# Eclipse XML Catalog: add XSD which imports or includes another XSD

Tags: xml, eclipse, validation, xsd, catalog

i want to add some XSD files to my Eclipse XML Catalog so it can validate XML files. Unfortunately the XSD includes and imports other XSD, and in turn they import other XSD files as well.

First XSD, BPMN20.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"   
    xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI"
    targetNamespace="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL">

    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" schemaLocation="BPMNDI.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="Semantic.xsd"/>
...
```

Second XSD, Semantic.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL">

    <xsd:element name="activity" type="tActivity"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="tActivity" abstract="true">
...
```

Eclipse immediately tells me that the second XSD can not be registered because it uses the same name space `http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL` under which i already registered the first XSD.

Is it possible to solve this issues of XSDs importing/including other XSDs with Eclipse?
I see lots of XSD files referencing other files, so it seems to be quite common to split type or attribute definitions and persist them in different files.

Thanks
Joysn

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid having different xsd files declaring the same namespace.
A namespace is a URI so it should identify a single resource.

Check this tutorial about how to use/define namespaces: http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Tutorials/XmlSchemas/XsdTutorial_04.aspx

Comment: yes, thats clear. but these are the official schema files from OMG, as u can see here http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100501/BPMN20.xsd.
Does this simply mean that OMG violates the XML/XSD spec?

Comment: Sorry Joysn, I missed the fact that it was included and not imported. Including a schema belonging to the same namespace is perfectly legal. Maybe you have to switch on an Eclipse option like "Honour all schema locations": http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.1.0/newandnoteworthy/sourceediting.php

Comment: no prob. unfortunately the "Honor all schema locations" is already activated in my Juno installation.